# Setting a System Wide path in Mac Yosemite

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, boost, path

I have installed boost libraries. I am using Eclipse to make a simple boost project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::filesystem::path path("/Users/schoen"); // random pathname
   bool result = boost::filesystem::is_directory(path);
    printf("Path is a directory : %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I have already set the path of include folder and library folder in the properties of this project. But I was getting a runtime error: `dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_system.dylib`. To solve this problem, I went to `run configuration` and set the environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/Users/myName/Documents/Softwares/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib`. This has solved my problem.

**What I need:** I don't want to set the `environment variable` for each Boost-based project. Therefore, I tried to set my `.bash_profile`. I wrote the following lines in `.bash_profile`.

```
# Following lines are for Boost Library
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/myName/Documents/Softwares/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

**PROBLEM:** By setting the variable in `.bash_profile`, I am able to run my program through the terminal. The program also runs if I open the IDE (e.g. Eclipse) via terminal and then run the application. Apparently, `.bash_profile` can set the variable for terminal applications. ***How can I set the path for windowed applications too?***

**PS:** This path setting problem is not just for Boost only, but I have to do similar things for other libraries too (such as OpenCV which is build/installed in a local directory).

Comment: You can launch GUI app by command, for example `open -a Adobe\ Photoshop\ CS`

Comment: @Krypton: Yes, that will also work. But I want that path variables can be regonized directly.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding a system wide path like this, you should add the rpath to the libraries to applications that depend on boost. To add the `rpath` option, you do `Project Properties` -> `C/C++ Build` -> `Settings` -> `Miscellaneous` and in the linker flags add:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/Users/myName/Documents/Softwares/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib
```

(this is if your linker is `g++` or `clang++`, for example)

If your linker is `ld` explicitly, then the option is

```
-rpath /Users/myName/Documents/Softwares/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib
```

although you may need to add `-macos_version_min 10.5` (or newer - probably 10.8 - this depends on the OS you're building on).

This will cause any applications built to search there for libraries as well as the default locations.

> Although a location like that to me looks a bit volatile

Turns out that boost builds without setting the library name to include `@rpath` in the install name, which means that even when you set the `-rpath` in the build, because the libraries aren't mentioned to be in the `@rpath`, it won't find them at run time. A workaround to this is to explicitly set the install name for the boost libraries, and their internal references to their own libraries:

```
#!/bin/bash -p 

for i in *.dylib; do 
    # set the rpath 
    install_name_tool -id @rpath/$i $i 
    for lib in $(otool -L $i | grep libboost | awk '{print $1}'); do 
        if [[ -f $lib ]]; then 
            install_name_tool -change $lib @rpath/$lib $i 
        fi 
    done 
done
```

This means the binaries that are linked to these boost libraries will respect the rpath setting.

You can repeat a similar process for other libraries to ensure that they respect rpath. The key element is the `install_name_tool -id "@rpath/libstuff.dylib" libstuff.dylib`, which says that when you link to the library record a reference to `@rpath/libstuff.dylib`. If libraries don't already have this set.

Secondly, for internal references to dependent libraries, the `-change` option alters references to the absolute name to an rpath relative name e.g. `install_name_tool -change "libstuff.dylib" "@rpath/libstuff.dylib" libdependsonlibstuff.dylib`. This can even be performed on a linked binary.

If you still want to set an environment variable, [there are some options available](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64916/defining-environment-variables-with-launchd-launchctl) which should help you getting a solution which works in that case.

Comment: Putting the above line throws a compile time error: `ld: unknown option: -Wl,-rpath,/Users/myName/Documents/Softwares/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib`

Comment: it sounds like your linker is `ld` rather than the compiler driver. In that case change it to `-rpath /Users/myName/Documents/Softwares/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib`. If you get a linker error related to minimal mac os versions, you'll also have to add `-macosx_version_min 10.5` as well.

Comment: after removing `-Wl`...I am getting `ld: unknown option: -rpath,/Users/myName/Documents/Softwares/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib `. There is no error related to the Mac version.

Comment: replace the comma with a space (i.e. `-rpath path`) the comma is if you need to send it through the compiler frontend, which, because you're using `ld` is not needed.

Comment: After your previous comment, there was no compile time error but again I am getting the same runtime error for which I posted the question :(

Comment: @skm the pathname as mentioned needs to be the same as where the boost libraries are located. Can you run `otool -l` on the resulting binary, and verify that there is an entry `LC_RPATH` containing the path to these libraries?

Comment: After running `otool -l` on the created binary, I can find that `LC_RPATH` contains the path of the libraries (i.e. `/Users/myName/Documents/Softwares/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib `)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90994/discussion-between-petesh-and-skm).